# How google docs shows my .PPT files without using a flash viewer?

Tags: java, c++, python, powerpoint, google-docs

I want to show .ppt (PowerPoint) files uploaded by my user on my website. I could do this by converting them into Flash files, then showing the Flash files on the web page. But I don't want to use Flash to do this. I want to show it, like google docs shows, without using Flash.

I've already solved the problem for .pdf files by converting them into images using ImageMagick, but now I have trouble with .ppt files.

Comment: Ask the Google Guys, maybe they will tell you ;)

Comment: Are there any google guys on SO. Pass us some hints. ;)

Comment: [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/), which also does this, has an [API](http://www.slideshare.net/developers) that allows you to upload slideshows to their service and then grab the code for embedding it on your site. Might be worth a look...

Comment: @fabrik:give the phone no. or the email address of a google guys i will surly ask him about this and lot more things...:)

Comment: @Matt Gibson:thanks i will try Slideshare API,but exactly i don't want to try API but anyways if i will not get any solution then i will use API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found a solution to showing .ppt file on my website without using the flash

the **solution** is:

just convert the .ppt file to .pdf files using any language or using software(e.g. open office) and then use Imagemagick to convert that .pdf into image and show to your web page

once again thanks to you all for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe try using [google docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to first upload a ppt presentation and then download it back in a different format. I think it should be possible though I have not tested it.

Comment: if you found any other solution in any language the please tell me :)

Comment: Well i did a quick google search for a PHP powerpoint library before posting this answer and I have not found any, and if it's not on google it doesn't exist, right? I still think using some kind of API is the easiest way to go here, whether it will be slideshare or google doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can [embed Google docs presentations](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86101) in your site.